# Strange! MySQL update not working without error

Tags: asp.net, mysql

The below is my code to create account in my project. The code is working perfect till `Response.Write(iduser)` but the UPDATE command is not working. No error found using exception but MySQL's record is not updated.

```
    try
                {

                    string pet1 = "admin@testlite.php";
                    string MyConString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=newtest;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=**********;" + "OPTION=3";
                    OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
                    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select id_user from awm_accounts where email=?", MyConnection);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = pet1;
                    MyConnection.Open();
                    OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows == false)
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int iduser = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
                        Account acct = new Account();
                        acct.Email = username.Text + domain.Text;
                        acct.MailIncomingLogin = username.Text + domain.Text;
                        acct.MailIncomingHost = "imap." + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                        acct.MailIncomingPassword = password.Text;
                        acct.MailIncomingPort = 993;
                        acct.MailOutgoingHost = "smtp." + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
                        acct.MailOutgoingPort = 465;
                        acct.MailIncomingProtocol = IncomingMailProtocol.Imap4;
                        acct.MailOutgoingAuthentication = true;
                        acct.DefaultAccount = false;
                        acct.IDUser = 1;
                        integr.CreateUserFromAccount(acct);
                        Response.Write(iduser);
                        if (!IsPostBack)
                        {
                            cmd = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE awm_accounts SET id_user=? WHERE email=? ", MyConnection);
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_nickname", OdbcType.Int, 11).Value = iduser;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tb_fullname", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = username.Text + domain.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                    MyConnection.Close();
                }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Response.Write(exp);
            }
```

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel with this? If so, remove it just until you have your bug fixed.

Comment: No. I am not using UpdatePanel in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `Response.Write` part but I am sure that you create a `SQLCommand` but never actually execute it.

Did you forget to put a `cmd.executeNonScalar()` in there?

Comment: Yeah! you are write. Just now I found I am missing `cmd.executenonquery` I added it and code worked fine. Thanks.